# No output with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am pretty new using scrapy and I want to scrape a website 'https://in.seamsfriendly.com/collections/shorts'
I have written the code but it giving traceback errors , Please help me in this

```
import scrapy
#from ..items import SeamsfriendlyItem

class SeamsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'seams'
    start_urls = [
        'https://in.seamsfriendly.com/collections/shorts'
        ]

    def parse(self, response):

        #items = SeamsfriendlyItem()


        #all_div_shorts = response.css('div.Grid__Cell 1/2--phone 1/2--tablet-and-up 1/3--desk')
        title : response.css("#shopify-section-collection-template a::text").extract()
        price : response.css(".Price::text").extract()
        url : response.css("img::attr(data-src)").extract()

        #items['title'] = title
        #items['url'] = url

        yield {
            'title' : title,
            'price' : price,
            'url' : url
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You typed `:` instead of `=`:

```py
import scrapy
#from ..items import SeamsfriendlyItem

class SeamsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'seams'
    start_urls = [
        'https://in.seamsfriendly.com/collections/shorts'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        #items = SeamsfriendlyItem()


        #all_div_shorts = response.css('div.Grid__Cell 1/2--phone 1/2--tablet-and-up 1/3--desk')
        title = response.css("#shopify-section-collection-template a::text").extract()
        price = response.css(".Price::text").extract()
        url = response.css("img::attr(data-src)").extract()

        #items['title'] = title
        #items['url'] = url

        yield {
            'title' : title,
            'price' : price,
            'url' : url
        }
```

Output:

```py
{'title': ['Elasticated', 'Casual', 'with Pockets', 'Printed', 'Solid', '\n    ',.............
```